# React Testing Library: How to remove an item from the Semantic UI Dropdown (in Multiple Selection mode)?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library, semantic-ui-react

[image: Screenshot of DOM code of Semantic UI Dropdown]

[image: Screenshot of Semantic UI Dropdown]

While building my tests, I've come up against an issue for which I can't find a solution.  Simply put, I want to remove the "Selects any" option from the Semantic UI Dropdown which I've previously added.  I've tried several approaches unsuccessfully to `fireEvent.click` on the little "X" that appears beside the text but none work.  Might anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try accessing to the `i` tag getting the label of your element? Something like:

```
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Selects any/).querySelector('i'));
```

**react-testing-library queries return DOM nodes.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried it but it didn't work.  Me and my colleagues are going to upgrade React Testing Library to the latest version and then I'll try again.

Comment: Actually @AdriSolid, I just revisited this.  Your precise syntax didn't work for me, but this does: `fireEvent.click(component.getByText(/Selects any/).querySelector('i'));` where `component` is what's returned by `renderDom`.  I believe this is due to the way we've setup our tests.